# Alter the dimensions of the canvas image permanently and NOT keep the aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, canvas, aspect-ratio, radial-gradients

I am creating a gradient on a canvas, generating a PNG file, and then downloading it. I want a radial gradient which is an ellipse. Since canvas gradients must be circles, I am generating the gradient as a circle and then resizing the canvas element to create the ellipse. This works fine and the visually generated image is the ellipse I want.

When I go to download the generated canvas, it is using the full size of the canvas, not the css styled size and so I get the original full sized circle. Is there a way to actually alter the dimensions of the canvas image and *NOT* keep the aspect ratio? All the SO posts that show up on the topic want to keep the aspect ratio.

```js
makeCanvas();
scaled();

var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "button";
input.style.display = "block";
input.value = "Download Canvas to PNG";
input.onclick = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  downloadURI(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"), "gradient.png");
}
document.body.appendChild(input);

var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "button";
input.style.display = "block";
input.value = "Download Scaled";
input.onclick = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("scaled");
  downloadURI(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"), "gradient.png");
}
document.body.appendChild(input);

function makeCanvas() {
  var canvasGradient;
  var ctx;
  width = 200;
  height = 200;
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.id = "canvas";
  canvas.style.width = width + "px";
  canvas.style.height = height + "px";
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var gradient;
  // both circles have to share the center of the canvas
  var coords = {
    x1: 0,
    y1: 0,
    x2: 0,
    y2: 0
  };
  coords.x1 = (width / 2);
  coords.x2 = coords.x1;
  coords.y1 = (height / 2);
  coords.y2 = coords.y1;
  // inner circle is just the center - a point
  coords.r1 = 0;
  // outer circle is the edge
  coords.r2 = Math.min(height, width);
  gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(coords.x1, coords.y1, coords.r1, coords.x2, coords.y2, coords.r2);
  gradient.addColorStop(0, "white");
  gradient.addColorStop(1, "black");
  ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
  canvas.style.width = width / 2 + "px";
  document.body.append(canvas);

  can = alter(canvas, ctx);
  //document.body.append(can);
}

function downloadURI(uri, name) {
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.download = name;
  link.href = uri;
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);
  delete link;
}

function alter(canvas, ctx) {
  var can = document.createElement("canvas");
  can.id = "can";
  can.width = Math.floor(canvas.width / 2);
  can.height = canvas.height;
  can.ctx = can.getContext("2d");
  can.ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, can.width, can.height);
  canvas.width = can.width;
  canvas.height = can.height;
  ctx.drawImage(can, 0, 0);
  return can;
}

function scaled() {
   var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.id = "scaled";
  canvas.style.width = "200px";
  canvas.style.height = "200px";
  canvas.width = 200;
  canvas.height = 200;
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var gradient;
 var g = ctx.createRadialGradient(100, 100, 0, 100, 100, 100);
  g.addColorStop(0, "white")
  g.addColorStop(1, "red")
  ctx.fillStyle = g
  ctx.scale(0.5, 1) // scale x axis 0.5
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200) // gradient circle squashed along x  
   document.body.append(canvas);
}
```

Comment: I find it very annoying that your sample code just went ahead and downloaded something to my computer. You should probably put that in a button.

Comment: @JDB Good point. Will fix.

Comment: @JDB - fixed. Now will only download with button press. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use transformations to change shape of gradients.

For your info gradient circles can be transformed to a ellipse.

```
var g = ctx.createRadialGradient(200,200,0,200,200,200)
g.addColorStop(0,"red")
g.addColorStop(1,"white")
ctx.fillStyle = g
ctx.scale(0.5,1) // scale x axis 0.5
ctx.fillRect(0,0,400,400)  // gradient circle squashed along x
```

### Scaling a canvas

Create a second canvas

```
// assuming canvas , ctx is the original canvas and context
var can = document.createElement("canvas");
```

Set the resolution

```
can.width = Math.floor(canvas.width / 2);
can.height = canvas.height;
```

Get context and draw original on new canvas

```
can.ctx = can.getContext("2d");
can.ctx.drawImage(canvas,0,0,can.width,can.height);
```

Set the original canvas to the new size

```
canvas.width = can.width;
canvas.height = can.height;
```

Draw on the scaled can onto the original canvas

```
ctx.drawImage(can,0,0);
can = undefined; // reference to dump temp canvas
```

You now have the canvas scale yet keeping the content. You could also just replace the old canvas with the new one

Comment: Thank you. I've got it working with the second canvas being added. Your first remark about setting the scale would be far preferable (much simpler), but when I download the PNG created, although the image is correctly scaled, the width of the file is double and the right half is blank. I added the scaled code to the bottom in my example and added as 2nd button to show the downloaded image. Is there any way to get the file dimensions correct without having to go through another canvas?

Comment: @mseifert To change the canvas size and keep the content requires a second canvas or you could use `getImageData` and `putImageData`. Draw what you need then `var data = ctx.getImageData(0,0,width/2,height); ctx.canvas.width /= 2; ctx.putImageData(data,0,0); `

Comment: Yes - `getImageData()` and `putImageData()` were exactly what I was hoping for. Short and sweet! Thanks again.